React Typescript: How to pass in FunctionComponent as Prop to another FunctionComponent
I am trying to create a reusable FunctionComponent called "BasicBlocks" that has a title, subtitle, and content (which is a FunctionComponent). This content is being passed into BasicBlocks but it is not rendering.
And I am getting these errors:
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
BasicBlocks
import React from "react";
import HomeStyle from "./home.module.css";
import ButtonStyle from "../styleDefs/buttons.module.css";
import BlockStyle from "../styleDefs/blocks.module.css";

interface BasicBlocksProps {
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  content?: React.FunctionComponent;
  size: string;
  center: boolean;
}

const BasicBlocks: React.FunctionComponent<BasicBlocksProps> = ({ title, subtitle, content, size, center }) => {
  return (

    // middle size
    <div className={size === "large" ? BlockStyle.large :
    size === "medium" ? BlockStyle.medium : BlockStyle.small}>
        {title && <h1 className={center ? BlockStyle.titleCenter : BlockStyle.titleLeft}>{title}</h1>}
        {subtitle && <div className={center ? BlockStyle.subtitleCenter : BlockStyle.subtitleLeft}>{subtitle}</div>}
        <div className={BlockStyle.content}>{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BasicBlocks;


import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SetInterval } from "./utilities";
import { basicBlock2 } from "../styleDefs/styles";
import ButtonStyle from "../styleDefs/buttons.module.css";
import BlockStyle from "../styleDefs/blocks.module.css";
import RobotStyle from "./robots.module.css";
import TableStyle from "../styleDefs/tableStyles.module.css";
import BasicBlocks from "./basicBlocks";

interface Robot {
  robot_name: string;
  connected: boolean;
  battery: number;
  active_user_id: number;
  active_user_first: string;
  active_user_last: string;
  robot_type: "simple" | "lilflo";
}

const Robots: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [robotArray, setRobotArray] = useState<Array<Robot>>([]);

  // Note this is coming from somewhere else, not vanilla
  SetInterval(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/robots/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setRobotArray(res.data.robots as Array<Robot>);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error fetching array of robots: " + err);
      });
  }, 1000 * 1);

  const robotRows = robotArray.map((robot) => {
    const canConnect =
      robot["active_user_first"] === null && robot["connected"];
    const hasBattery =
      !(robot["battery"] === null);
    let connectionString;
    if (robot.robot_type === "lilflo") {
      connectionString = `/controller/${robot["robot_name"]}`;
    } else if (robot.robot_type === "simple") {
      connectionString = `/simple-controller/${robot["robot_name"]}`;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <tr key={robot.robot_name}>
        <td >{robot["robot_name"]}</td>
        <td>{robot["connected"].toString()}</td>
        <td>{hasBattery || "Not Available"}</td>
        <td>{robot["active_user_first"]}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  const Page: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (<div>hello</div>);
  }
  const RobotsPage: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
      <div style={basicBlock2}>
        <table className={TableStyle.table}>
            <thead >
              <tr >
                <th className={TableStyle.tableHead} >Robot Name</th>
                <th className={TableStyle.tableHead} >Connected</th>
                <th className={TableStyle.tableHead} >Battery</th>
                <th className={TableStyle.tableHead} >Active User</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>{robotRows}</tbody>
        </table>
        <div className={ButtonStyle.buttonWrapperCenter}>
          <button 
          className={ButtonStyle.addButton}
          onClick={(): void => {
            // axios.post("/api/users/logout").then(
            //   () => {
            //     // request succeeded
            //     setLoggedIn(false);
            //     setUserName("");
            //   },
            //   (err) => {
            //     alert("failed to logout: " + err.response.data["error"]);
            //   }
            // );
          }}>
            add robot
          </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <BasicBlocks title={"Robot List"} subtitle={"suck it"} size={"large"} center={false} content={Page}> 
      
      
    </BasicBlocks>
    
  );
};

export default Robots;

I've tried changing the component type to React.Component or React.ComponentType but those did not work with my syntax. Also, I've tried other methods in standard ReactJS which does not match the TypeScript syntax.

const Content = content; <Content />

First, you can render a component in a variable by making sure it starts with a capital letter and rendering it like any any other component.
const MyComponent = component
return <MyComponent />


Second, you shouldn't be using the React.FunctionComponent type. It's not necessary for your own components, and it will exclude pass based components if someone else wants to pass those in. What you really care about is that
the component you pass takes no props.
You probably want the React.ComponentType for that.

That leads us to this simplified example. (I removed the bits that were really not relevant to your question, feel free to add them back in).
import React from "react";

interface BasicBlocksProps {
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  content?: React.ComponentType;
}

function BasicBlocks({ title, subtitle, content: ContentComponent }: BasicBlocksProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {title && <h1>{title}</h1>}
      {subtitle && <div>{subtitle}</div>}
      <div>{ContentComponent && <ContentComponent /> }</div>
    </div>
  );
};

Note how the content is remapped to the ContentComponent local variable, and then can be rendered with <ContentComponent />.
See Playground

Lastly, It may better serve you to make the caller render what you want. This lets that caller pass in whatever props it wants, if necessary.
This means that you would accept a prop of type React.ReactNode, like this:
import React from "react";

interface BasicBlocksProps {
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  content?: React.ReactNode;
}

function BasicBlocks({ title, subtitle, content }: BasicBlocksProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {title && <h1>{title}</h1>}
      {subtitle && <div>{subtitle}</div>}
      <div>{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

And then when you render this component, you fully render some other component for the content prop:
function Foo() { return <>foo</> }
const test = <BasicBlocks content={<Foo />} /> // fine

See Playground
